# Modal Grid not displaying properly, maybe because ::before and ::after

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple modal in C# & ASP.NET MVC; I added 2 text boxes in a col-6 layout so they would be side by side I tried quiet a few different techniques and the only way I got it to work was if I did a table with a row and 2 cols in the row but they don’t came out the exact same size. So I'm trying to do the col-6 with bootstrap grid so they will be the same. In my Dev tools I see ::before and ::after maybe this has something to do with messing up the layout.

Here the 2 text boxes are in block layout 1 on top of each other

```
<div class="container-fluid mx-auto">
    <div class="row d-inline">
        <div class="col-6 d-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I use the bootstrap grid so they come out the same size and on the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use col instead of col-6. Also, using the form-inline might help. There are a lot of things you can do to format your form how you want it using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/) . Also, Bootstrap uses @media breakpoints, which changes the layout based on the screen size.

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="container-fluid mx-auto">
    <div class="row d-inline">
        <div class="col d-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PartVM.PartNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PartVM.DateEntered, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: same thing did not do anything.. did this work for you? not for me in my modal..

Comment: You might have to put the form element inside the container-fluid div and no I didn’t test this code